How to create custom terraform module for ZScaler Cloud connector creation from github on GCP?
I want to create Zscaler Cloud connector on GCP referring below Github public modules. But from this module I only want to create Cloud Connector and Internal Load Balancer.
https://github.com/zscaler/terraform-gcp-cloud-connector-modules/tree/main/examples
Folder base_1cc and base_cc_ilb is required but with limited resources.
While trying to use this TF code, it creates network, subnet, IP range, FW rules but failes while creating instance template.
I have my VPC, subnets and FW rules already in-place, so only Zscaler CC and Internal LB to be created.
Kindly advise how to create customized repository locally for specific resources from Github.
I have tried following below Zscaler Article for deployment but as mentioned it creates everything except Cloud Connector template.
https://help.zscaler.com/cloud-branch-connector/deploying-zscaler-cloud-connector-google-cloud-platform
As mentioned VPC, subnet and FW rules are already inplace, so want to use brownfield approach for Production deployments.
